# How do I capitalize the first letter of a string in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, concatenation

I have the following document in my MongoDB:

```
{
    name: "BRIAN"
}
```

I'm trying to change it to this format:

```
{
    name: "Brian"
}
```

I've tried the following:

```
{
    $project: {
       name: { $concat: [ { $toLower: '$name' } ]}
    }
}
```

So this makes the string lowercase, then I just need to make the first letter uppercase. Is it possible to do that within the same project aggregation?

Comment: Check [$substrCP](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v4.4/reference/operator/aggregation/substrCP/#mongodb-expression-exp.-substrCP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Wernfried Domscheit suggested, you can use `$substrCP` to segment `name` and perform `$toLower` separately for the "tail" and keep the first character upper case. Use `$concat` to put back the 2 results together.

```js
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "name": {
        "$concat": [
          {
            "$substrCP": [
              "$name",
              0,
              1
            ]
          },
          {
            "$toLower": {
              "$substrCP": [
                "$name",
                1,
                {
                  "$strLenCP": "$name"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AXq2P8nEPq7)